# Error efecto Shadow , blur en PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy generando una pequeña interfaz pero al intentar agregar un efecto de sombra(DropShadowEffect) y un efecto blur(), me arroja un error:

Este es mi codigo.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication ,QLabel, QGraphicsEffect, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QGraphicsBlurEffect
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class Pinricpal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)


        self.resize(97,98)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("Verticallayout")
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Nuevo")

        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropSahowEffect()
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(5)
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)



app = QApplication([])
principal = Pinricpal()
principal.show()
app.exec_()
```

**COMO PREGUNTA EXTRA: ¿Es posible implementar este efecto al background de un MainWindow?**

Comment: Hola Revsky01, siempre es positivo que muestres el error. A simple vista solo veo que tienes un error tipográfico en `self.shadow = QGraphicsDropSahowEffect()`, falta una "d" y la "h" está en el lugar incorrecto en "Shadow", debería ser  `self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()`.

Comment: No me había percatado de ese error, funciona perfecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication ,QLabel, 
                             QGraphicsEffect, QVBoxLayout, 
                             QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QGraphicsBlurEffect,
                             QWidget)                         # +
#from PyQt5 import uic
#from PyQt5.QtGui import *
#from PyQt5.QtCore import *
#from PyQt5 import QtGui

class Pinricpal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.wid = QWidget()                                   # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.wid)                        # +

        self.resize(97,98)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.wid)            # -self
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("Verticallayout")

        self.label = QLabel(self)     
        self.label.setText("Hello Revsky01")

        #self.shadow = QGraphicsDropSahowEffect()              # -
        self.shadow  = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()             # +
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(3)
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)



app = QApplication([])
principal = Pinricpal()
principal.show()
app.exec_()
```